# SVG animation issue

Tags: animation, svg

Cannot work out why the g element is not being animated

```css
#circle{
width:100px;
height:100px;
position:relative;
animation-name:ex2;
animation-duration:4s;
animation-iteration-count:2;
}

@keyframes ex2{
0% {left:0px; top:0px;}
50% {left:200px; top:0px;}
100%{left:0px; top:0px;}
 }
```

```html
<g id="circle">
  <circle  class="st1" cx="320" cy="567.5" r="136"/>
</g>
```

I have tried it inline as well as using the object tag and neither works.

Comment: It's not in an `svg`, there's a lingering orphan tag at the end of `circle`, the positioning, lack of vendor prefixes, where to start?

Comment: Are you just trying to make something bounce a couple times on the x axis?

Comment: left and top are not properties that <g> elements support (or indeed any SVG element other than outer <svg> elements support).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As everybody commented left and top are not properties of `g` elements. Next comes a demo where I'm using css transform instead.

```css
svg{border:1px solid}

#circle{
animation-name:ex2;
animation-duration:4s;
animation-iteration-count:2;
}

@keyframes ex2{
0% {transform:translate(0px,0px);}
50% {transform:translate(200px,0px);}
100%{transform:translate(0px,0px);}
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox ="0 400 700 400">
<g id="circle">
  <circle  class="st1" cx="320" cy="567.5" r="136"/>
</g>
</svg>
```